# Understanding the Security of Firebase App Initialization

Tags: javascript, firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm trying to create an expo app without the use of a server as a middleman between the front end and firestore. Via the [firestore quickstart ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) and [expo firestore quickstart](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase/) (see bottom), it says to initialize a cloud firestore app by passing in an API key to the following function:

```
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '### FIREBASE API KEY ###',
  authDomain: '### FIREBASE AUTH DOMAIN ###',
  projectId: '### CLOUD FIRESTORE PROJECT ID ###'
});

var db = firebase.firestore();
```

However this javascript code will be run on the client side. Doesn't this expose your API key to a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From google firebase docs:

> The content is considered public, including your platform-specific ID
>   (entered in the Firebase console setup workflow) and values that are
>   specific to your Firebase project, like your **API Key**, Realtime
>   Database URL, and Storage bucket name. Given this, use security rules
>   to protect your data and files

You can read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#config-files-objects)